# How to inject dynamic javascript code into an iframe that already exists on parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, dynamic, inject

I am trying to inject code into an iframe but I haven't had any luck and I'm not sure why. I store my js code into a variable, which works properly at this point, into a variable called pixel_code. I then want to inject that code into the iframe. Assuming the id of the iframe is "iframe_" how would I inject the code (variable is pixel_code) into the iframe and execute it? I think jquery would be the easiest way, but I'm open to regular JS as well.

One of my many unsuccessful attempts is:

```
function captureValue(){

pixel_code = document.getElementById("baseText").value;

$('#iframe_').find('body').append(pixel_code);

}
```

No errors are generated in the console.

Comment: Is the iframe and the parent page in the same domain?

Comment: I am running on a localhost, so I assumed the answer would be yes. Is that incorrect? Here's the error I get http://cl.ly/image/3k1s0q212a0a

Comment: Appears that you are not using the http:// protocol. May you paste the HTML part that you call the iframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `contents` method:

```
$('#iframe_').contents().find('body').append(pixel_code);
```

Note that domain of the iframe should match with the domain of the parent page, otherwise  [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) prevents accessing the iframe's contents.